# Как при помощи оператора like найти все записи, которые НЕ заканчиваются на определенный текст?

Tags: sql

Как при помощи оператора like найти все записи, которые не заканчиваются на "_past". Нужно использовать like, не not like.

Работаю на старом проекте. Для доступа к базе можно использовать только один класс, в нём нету этой операции, поэтому надо так изощряться. База postgresql. Надо придумать строку для подобного запроса: `select * from MyTable where name like` "строка", в результате выполнения которого будут найдены все записи, у которых name не будет заканчиваться на _past.

Comment: @ruslan5t а почему нельзя `not like`? Может можно и с ним?

     select * from t where t not like '%\_past';

Comment: в Mysql во всяком случае есть NOT LIKE

Answer (score 4):

сделайте вложенный запрос. Первым (внутренним) отберите все записи, которые заканчиваются на "_past", а вторым (внешним) найдите все записи, которые не входят в данных набор.

Но для более точного ответа, нужно знать, какой движок базы данных Вы используете и зачем нужно такое извращение (учебное задание, база данных не поддерживает not like, хочется поизголятся, плохая производительность).

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
declare @t TABLE (a varchar(20))
insert into @t values('aaa_past'),('notpast'),('_past_nnn')

select * from @t
except
select * from @t where a like '%|_past' escape '|';
```

[LIKE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_predicate_like/page2.html)